# unique basis solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this in my text:

[image]

I don't know how they arrived at the second set of equations starting with:

$$c_1 = -u_1 + 4u_2 ...$$

What is going on?

Also how do they know that A is invertible? Is it because of the determinant? If so, I guess I'm lost as to why a nonzero determinant implies a unique solution?

Comment: I’m sure that this must have been explained earlier in your text. I recommend going back and reviewing that material.

Comment: It is true that a square matrix is invertible if and only if it has non-zero determinant. However, it is an important thing to know that a square matrix is invertible (that is, always has unique solutions for each right side of the equation) if and only if the columns form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since the matrix in question is formed by taking a basis and using the basis vectors for the columns of the matrix, the resulting matrix will be invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic linear algebra, cf. any introductory material. 
The new system of equations, and also invertibility of the matrix $A$ can be justified by Gaussian elimination, for example.

Answer (score 1):

[Compute the inverse](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Inverse-of-a-3x3-Matrix) of the matrix $A$.

Then when you multiply on the left of [image] by the $A^{-1}$ you found, you get an equality of matrices which can be translated into the second system of equations.